# finding the next row with a particular value

Tags: r, loops

My input is the first three columns:    `ID COLLECTED_DATE  Hyperkalemia`

My output is the last three columns: `met_criteria  my_row  next_1_time_interval`

Met_criteria = Hyperkalemia == 3 | 4

My_row = row at which Hyperkalemia == 1 following a 3 or 4 value (within the same ID)

next_1_time_interval == time between the 3 or 4 value and the time 1 value (within the same ID)

```
> ROW ID COLLECTED_DATE Hyperkalemia met_criteria my_row next_1_time_interval
1  123  1   5/25/08 3:30            0           NA     NA                   NA
2  124  1   5/26/08 3:30            0           NA     NA                   NA
3  125  1   5/27/08 4:00            2           NA     NA                   NA
4  126  1   5/28/08 3:45            2           NA     NA                   NA
5  127  1   5/29/08 3:40            3         TRUE    248         5.590500e+04
6  128  1   5/29/08 6:40            2           NA     NA                   NA
7  129  1  5/29/08 20:15            2           NA     NA                   NA
8  144  1   6/13/08 4:00            0           NA     NA                   NA
9  145  1   6/14/08 4:10            0           NA     NA                   NA
10 146  1   6/15/08 4:45            4         TRUE    248         5.549592e+04
11 147  1   6/15/08 6:30            0           NA     NA                   NA
12 246  1 12/18/12 10:46            0           NA     NA                   NA
13 247  1  1/14/14 11:30            0           NA     NA                   NA
14 248  1 10/14/14 12:40            1           NA     NA                   NA
15 249  1   2/4/15 14:27            0           NA     NA                   NA
16 633  2   9/12/14 4:30            0           NA     NA                   NA
17 634  2   9/29/14 8:57            0           NA     NA                   NA
18 635  3   12/6/11 2:50            0           NA     NA                   NA
19 636  3  12/6/11 10:45            0           NA     NA                   NA
20 637  3  12/6/11 17:50            0           NA     NA                   NA
21 704  3   4/18/12 5:00            0           NA     NA                   NA
22 705  3   4/18/12 5:00            0           NA     NA                   NA
23 706  3  4/18/12 16:30            3         TRUE    708         8.333333e-01
24 707  3  4/18/12 16:30            4         TRUE    708         8.333333e-01
25 708  3  4/18/12 17:20            1           NA     NA                   NA
26 768  3   5/10/12 3:35            0           NA     NA                   NA
27 769  3   5/11/12 3:20            0           NA     NA                   NA
28 770  3   5/12/12 4:00            4         TRUE     NA                   NA
29 771  3   5/12/12 5:45            0           NA     NA                   NA
30 772  3   5/13/12 4:00            0           NA     NA                   NA
31 773  3   5/14/12 5:30            0           NA     NA                   NA
32 774  3   5/15/12 4:00            4         TRUE     NA                   NA
33 775  3   5/15/12 5:15            0           NA     NA                   NA
34 776  3   5/16/12 8:34            0           NA     NA                   NA
35 777  3   5/17/12 7:10            0           NA     NA                   NA
36 778  3   5/18/12 7:10            0           NA     NA                   NA
37 779  3   5/28/12 7:26            0           NA     NA                   NA
38 780  3   6/20/12 9:46            0           NA     NA                   NA
39 781  3   8/1/12 13:10            0           NA     NA                   NA
40 782  3 11/14/12 13:34            0           NA     NA                   NA
41 783  3  11/13/13 9:35            0           NA     NA                   NA
42 784  3    6/5/15 9:31            0           NA     NA                   NA
```

The output listed is the desired output.

The rows to look at are : 127, 146 ( 3 or 4 of Hyperkalemia) and 248 (hyperkalemia of 1 following a 3 or 4 value) with each row belonging to one person's ID.

Also: rows 706, 707: (3 or 4 value in Hyperkalemia.
708: 1 value following a 3 or 4 value (Hyperkalemia) for the same ID

```
    pots_1 <- arrange(pots_1, MRN, COLLECTED_DATE)

    pots_1$Hyperkalemia[is.na(pots_1$Hyperkalemia)] <- 0
    pots_1$met_criteria <- NA
    pots_1$next_1_time_interval <- NA
    pots_1$my_row <- NA 


   # data.frame = pots
   # for every patient  (sorted by mrn and collected date) 
   for (mrn in unique(pots_1$MRN)){ 

      # for each row for each patient (sorted by collected date)
      for (i in 1:length(which(pots_1$MRN == mrn))) {

       # number of rows for this mrn
        mrn_max_row <- length(which(pots_1$MRN == mrn))

        # if Hyperkalemia = 3 or 4 
        if(pots_1$Hyperkalemia[i] == 3 | pots_1$Hyperkalemia[i] == 4){
         my_start_row <- i
         my_row <- i
         pots_1$met_criteria[i] <- TRUE

         #for every row after 3 or  4 until I get to Hyperkalemia = 1
          while (pots_1$Hyperkalemia[my_row] != 1){
          my_row <- my_row+1 
          if (my_row > mrn_max_row) {
           break
          }

      } # ends while 
      if (pots_1$Hyperkalemia[my_row]) {
      pots_1$my_row[i] <- my_row
      pots_1$next_1_time_interval[my_start_row] <- difftime(pots_1$COLLECTED_DATE[my_row], pots_1$COLLECTED_DATE[my_start_row], units = "hours")
      }
      # break only marks the first one if break is here

      } # ends if

    } # ends loop through mrn result rows

  } # ends loop through mrns
```

This code works correctly, but only for the first ID. I've tried a number of things to get this working for the entire set of IDs and have gotten a number of interesting errors :) like calculating for the next value regardless of ID.

Could someone help me get this working for the entire ID set?

This is written in R. I realize for loops and while statements are not typical in R, however I only have 7500 rows and it runs very fast regardless of the loops.

Comment: try using `dput()` on some of your data; it would help us reproduce your situation

Comment: From the "answer" you expect, the desired result for the 4th column is TRUE whenever Hyperkalemia is 3 or 4 and for the fifth column is the rowname of the first row where 'Hyperkalemia' is 1. (Not "how long was it until the next value of Hyperkalemia = 1" whatever that phrase might mean.) It remains totally unclear what the 6 column might be.

Comment: I had tried to edit the phrasing. Met_criteria = TRUE when Hyperkalemia = 3 or 4. My_row is the next row (for same ID) following the 3 or 4 where the value of Hyperkalemia is 1. next_1_time_interval is the time from the collected_value where Hyperkalemia was 3 or 4 to the time when Hyperkalemia was 1 (for the same ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[,COLLECTED_DATE:=
  as.POSIXct(COLLECTED_DATE,format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")]
```

The easy part:

```
x[,met_criteria:=Hyperkalemia %in% 3:4]
```

Now, defining `my_row` is somewhat complicated-looking. Check previous edits if you want a breakdown of where this came from.

```
x[,my_row:=zoo::na.locf(NA^(Hyperkalemia!=1)*.I,
                        fromLast=T,na.rm=F)*NA^(!met_criteria),by=ID]
```

Now `next_1_time_interval` comes pretty easily:

```
x[,next_1_time_interval:=difftime(COLLECTED_DATE[my_row],
                                  COLLECTED_DATE,
                                  units="hours")]
> x
    ROW ID      COLLECTED_DATE Hyperkalemia met_criteria my_row next_1_time_interval
 1: 123  1 2008-05-25 03:30:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
 2: 124  1 2008-05-26 03:30:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
 3: 125  1 2008-05-27 04:00:00            2        FALSE     NA             NA hours
 4: 126  1 2008-05-28 03:45:00            2        FALSE     NA             NA hours
 5: 127  1 2008-05-29 03:40:00            3         TRUE     14   5.590500e+04 hours
 6: 128  1 2008-05-29 06:40:00            2        FALSE     NA             NA hours
 7: 129  1 2008-05-29 20:15:00            2        FALSE     NA             NA hours
 8: 144  1 2008-06-13 04:00:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
 9: 145  1 2008-06-14 04:10:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
10: 146  1 2008-06-15 04:45:00            4         TRUE     14   5.549592e+04 hours
11: 147  1 2008-06-15 06:30:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
12: 246  1 2012-12-18 10:46:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
13: 247  1 2014-01-14 11:30:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
14: 248  1 2014-10-14 12:40:00            1        FALSE     NA             NA hours
15: 249  1 2015-02-04 14:27:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
16: 633  2 2014-09-12 04:30:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
17: 634  2 2014-09-29 08:57:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
18: 635  3 2011-12-06 02:50:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
19: 636  3 2011-12-06 10:45:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
20: 637  3 2011-12-06 17:50:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
21: 704  3 2012-04-18 05:00:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
22: 705  3 2012-04-18 05:00:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
23: 706  3 2012-04-18 16:30:00            3         TRUE     25   8.333333e-01 hours
24: 707  3 2012-04-18 16:30:00            4         TRUE     25   8.333333e-01 hours
25: 708  3 2012-04-18 17:20:00            1        FALSE     NA             NA hours
26: 768  3 2012-05-10 03:35:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
27: 769  3 2012-05-11 03:20:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
28: 770  3 2012-05-12 04:00:00            4         TRUE     NA             NA hours
29: 771  3 2012-05-12 05:45:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
30: 772  3 2012-05-13 04:00:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
31: 773  3 2012-05-14 05:30:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
32: 774  3 2012-05-15 04:00:00            4         TRUE     NA             NA hours
33: 775  3 2012-05-15 05:15:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
34: 776  3 2012-05-16 08:34:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
35: 777  3 2012-05-17 07:10:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
36: 778  3 2012-05-18 07:10:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
37: 779  3 2012-05-28 07:26:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
38: 780  3 2012-06-20 09:46:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
39: 781  3 2012-08-01 13:10:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
40: 782  3 2012-11-14 13:34:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
41: 783  3 2013-11-13 09:35:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
42: 784  3 2015-06-05 09:31:00            0        FALSE     NA             NA hours
    ROW ID      COLLECTED_DATE Hyperkalemia met_criteria my_row next_1_time_interval
```

Comment: Thanks, the output example I gave is correct, that's really what I'm going for. I manually created it to test. I am not sure how to format it better? How did you format this?

Comment: See the second line I gave. I formatted your time variable as `POSIXct` (see `?POSIXct` and `?as.POSIXct` for more)

Comment: Oh my time variable is fine, I have had no problems with it, it's formatted as time. I believe people are talking about the lack of tab spacing

Comment: RStudio did that for me. Just do `x` or `print(x)` and it should automatically space.

Comment: Thanks!! That works, and I'm surprised how clear it is despite not using for loops. Except that I'm getting all NA values for next_1_time_interval. Is there a missing index on the second COLLECTED_DATE for difftime or something? (At that point I want to take difftime between collected_date[my_row] and the collected date where met_criteria = TRUE (by ID).) Can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85011/discussion-between-soporific-and-michaelchirico).